# Zend Feed Import Exception Handling

Tags: zend-framework, feed, reader

I have a php code written in Zend Framework to import RSS Feeds from URLS.
Here is my code:

```
$slashdotRss = Reader::import($url);
```

It works fine on

> http://iafrica.tv/feed

But gives error on

> http://iafrica.tv

Error is given below:

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\AveroxProjects\BleupageDev\vendor\zendframework\zend-feed\src\Reader\Reader.php(250): Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader::importString('')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\AveroxProjects\BleupageDev\module\Bleupage\src\Bleupage\Model\rssFeed.php(17): Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader::import('http://iafrica....')
```

**Message**

```
Only non empty strings are allowed as input
```

My question is how I can handle this exception so that a proper message is displayed to user instead of the error without turning off exception.

Comment: you should use a try catch arround your imports statements and handle the exception in the catch.
also check about finally keyword to close the open feed if needed

Comment: I am already using try catch, can you please elaborate about the finally keyword.

Comment: So you are properly catching the exeption, you have to handle it now. Could you show some more code ?  All within the try/catch would be great. 
More info on finally here : http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php